# Servlet Filter after session time out problems

Tags: java, session, redirect, servlet-filters

i have Servlet Filter whith session time out check:

```
 @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    String uri = req.getRequestURI();
    if (req.getUserPrincipal() == null && !uri.endsWith("login.xhtml") && uri.endsWith("xhtml")) {
        res.reset();
        res.setHeader("Location", "/nsi/faces/login.xhtml");
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND);
        res.setContentType("xhtml");
        //  filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        // req.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/faces/login.xhtml").forward(req, res);
    } else {
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

why when session timed out redirect not working  ?
I`am try to use HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect and HttpServletResponse forward. 
P.s. get request redirected , but POST request entrer in the  method and  do nothing;

Answer (score 0):

In JSF you can do it this way

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                    .redirect("/faces/login.xhtml");

Comment: this method throw  java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

After `response.sendRedirect("/faces/login.xhtml");` you should do a `return;`.

The following filter will redirect all requests to the root url to google.nl:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class RedirectFilter implements Filter {

    public void destroy() {}

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        res.sendRedirect("https://www.google.nl");
        return;
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}

}
```

Comment: "return"  in if-else block  do nothing))

Comment: I added an example filter which redirects all calls to www.google.nl.

Comment: Have you tried the exact code I posted? That works both with GET and POST on JBoss EAP 6.1.

Comment: I`m try your method and it`s works with GET and POST methods before session teim out, after only GET redirected; WildFly 8.2